# HTML 5, ASP.NET 4.5 TextBox TextMode

Tags: asp.net, html

Good Day, I just want to ask if it's possible to block past dates in TextBox TextMode = "Date"? Thank you guys!

*Update 
there is a way to block dates in TextMode="DateTimeLocal"?
If I use Date it's okay, but when I changed the TextMode to DateTimeLocal it's not working.

`min=TextBoxArrival.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`
This code is working on TextMode="Date"
 
This code is from : Mr @Darin Dimitrov

Thank you!

Comment: This could help: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-and-time-state-(type=datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`min`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.min) attribute:

```
<input type="date" min="2013-02-24" value="2013-02-24" />
```

There's also a [`max`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.max) attribute you could use to restrict the maximum date that could be selected in the field.

Also don't forget that this is not validation. You should make sure that you perform this validation on your server and not rely on client side.

Comment: how can i use the datetime.now in min? :/

Comment: Like this: `min="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>"`.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxArrival" runat="server" min="<%=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox> - Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs. can you help me about this? @Darin

Comment: You could set the `min` attribute in your code behind: `TextBoxArrival.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` or simply use a normal input field as shown in my answer where you will be able to directly set the `min` value.