# ASP.NET 4.5 TextBox TextMode

Tags: asp.net

It's possible to block past dates in ASP.net TextBox TextMode = "DateTime" or "Date"

Comment: On the post, block them - filter them. How the user write the dates ? do you use any control that show that dates ? Please give some more informations, your question is very poor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML 5, ASP.NET 4.5 TextBox TextMode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050136/html-5-asp-net-4-5-textbox-textmode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050136/html-5-asp-net-4-5-textbox-textmode)

> [Input element specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime%29) The min attribute, if specified, must
>   have a value that is a valid global date and time string. The max
>   attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid global date
>   and time string

You will probably do this from code behind

```
yourTextBox.Attributes.Add("min", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: This is a client-side attribute that is not enforced by the server, a user (using an older browser or an attacker sending rogue requests) will be able to submit invalid values.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is WebForms, in which case yes, you can use a `RangeValidator`. Like so:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dateField" />
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="dateField" 
MaximumValue="9999/12/28" 
MinimumValue="1000/12/28" 
ErrorMessage="enter valid date" />
```

You'll need to set the `MinimumValue` attribute as appropriate. You can do this from your codebehind, or an in-page `<script>` block:

```
this.rangeValidator.MinimumValue = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract( new TimeSpan(13,0,0) ).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note my use of `UtcNow` and subtracting 13 hours to get a true, globally-acceptable, minimum date value. You might want to change this as appropriate for your application (such as restricting it to the timezone of your server provided that's what your users expect).